# How do I track the activity of logged in users?

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications

I have a Larval application and have many members. I want to track the activity of the logged in users on my website. Is there a way I can see the links of the pages the logged in user go to within my website and store them on my database?

Comment: Create a redirection function and replace all of your links on every page with this redirection function, also make the redirection function record the user and the link clicked in your database. Basically all links could point to a php file like `redirect.php` where you pass the actual link as a variable, use `header("Location: $_GET['link'])` to do the redirect, but before that store `$_GET['link']` to your db with the userid of whoever clicked it.

Comment: What about using already existing tools like [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none) to track this kind of stuff? If you're looking for a quick and simple solution though, @GrumpyCrouton gave you a great method of doing so

Comment: use this package https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

Comment: You can use middleware to log User Data along with the URL, Request Parameters and Request Method

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user meta field in your database which holds a json data, You can keep track of url using the Request object such as

```
// Full URL, with query string
$request->fullUrl()

// Just the path part of the URL 
$request->path()

// Just the root (protocol and domain) part of the URL)
$request->root()
```

Now you can update the database field using 
  let **$dbVal** is the value of the column you used to store tracking data as json array.

```
$newField=json_encode(array_push(json_decode($dbval),$request->path()))
```

Here in this way you can maintain records for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

To track the activities of logged in users on your laravel website use `https://mixpanel.com/`
It is paid one but here you can track each and every thing about user like when user register, geolocation, clicks,page vist etc
reffer mixpanel doc - https://mixpanel.com/help/reference
Hope this will help you.